# How to make this grey kind of background with css?

Tags: html, css, background, web

I wonder how the background on the following page has been made?
http://www.wohn-blogger.de/page/4/

As you can see the background is not a plain color. Is it an image that scales to the whole page? Or can this even be achieved with css somehow?

The reason why I'm asking is that the css contains the following:

```
body {
    background: #0d1424 url(images/body-bg.jpg) no-repeat center top;
    font: .81em/150% "Lucida Grande", Arial, "Lucida Sans Unicode", sans-serif;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    color: #666;
}
```

Which would mean this is a single image that is not repeated. Anyhow how comes that the whole page is filled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS:

```
body {
    background: url("http://www.wohn-blogger.de/wp-content/themes/itheme2/skins/gray/images/body-bg.png") repeat scroll 0 0 #D1D1D1;
    color: #666666;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I lost part of my question. Updated above.

Comment: Oh I see, probably I was looking at the wrong css file. This makes it very clear, ty!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this. It appears to be composed of a transparent gradient image and a texture image. In this case, I would approach this by adding the repeating texture to the html element and the transparent gradient to the body element.

```
html {background:url(texture.png);)
body {background:url(gradient.png) top left repeat-x;)
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the website has two body styles defined, the no-repeat getting overriden by a standard repeating background image.

[image]